# Solve: $(x + y)\,\mathrm dx + (y-x)\,\mathrm dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(x + y)\,\mathrm dx + (y-x)\,\mathrm dy = 0$$
Comparing it with $M\,\mathrm dx + N\,\mathrm dy = 0$, we get $M = (x + y)$, $N = (y-x)$. Now, $\dfrac{\partial M}{\partial y} = 1$, also, $\dfrac{\partial N}{\partial x} = -1$. $\dfrac{\partial M}{\partial y} \neq \dfrac{\partial N}{\partial x}$, so the equation is not exact.

Now,
$$\frac{1}{M} \left(\frac{\partial N}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\right) = \frac{-2}{x + y}\\
\frac{1}{N}\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}\right) = \frac{2}{y-x}$$

Here none of them are only function of $y$ or $x$ how to solve it from here?

The given answer is $\arctan\dfrac{y}{x} - \dfrac{1}{2} \ln(x^2 + y^2)$.

Comment: HINT: Use the substitution $y=kx$ for some constant $k$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(x + y) dx + (y-x) dy = 0$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{x+y}{x-y}$

Use substitution $y = x u \implies dy = u dx + x du$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = u + x \dfrac{du}{dx}$

So, $x \dfrac{du}{dx} = \dfrac{1+u}{1-u} - u$

$\dfrac{dx}{x} = \dfrac{1-u}{1+u^2} du$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yeah I can. Actually I was biased toward exact differential way, so I was stuck.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}
(x + y) dx + (y-x) dy &= 0\\
x \, dx +y \, dy +(y \, dx - x \, dy)&=0\\
\frac{1}{2}dx^2 +\frac{1}{2} dy^2 +(y \, dx - x \, dy)&=0\\
\frac{1}{2}d(x^2+y^2) +(y \, dx - x \, dy)&=0\\
\frac{1}{2(x^2+y^2)}d(x^2+y^2) +\frac{(y \, dx - x \, dy)}{x^2+y^2}&=0\\
\frac{d(x^2+y^2)}{2(x^2+y^2)}+\frac{d\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)}{1+\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2}&=0.
\end{align*}
Now integrate to get
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+y^2)+ \arctan\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)= C$$